# Sharepoint Online - JSOM WorkflowInstanceServices CountInstances method returning nothing

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, jsom

I am trying to query all the workflows with a specific state ('started') from a list with javascript (or the first one, since only one workflow "can" be running).
Using the InstanceService I can query all the instances (including 'completed') of workflows in the list, but querying those requires a lot of time (for 100 items). I tried getting all the WorkflowSubscriptions (which worked fine), and then using the `CountInstancesWithStatus` method (see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.workflowinstanceservice.countinstanceswithstatus.aspx)). I pass the subscription into the function, and already tried the numeric and the textual values for the status, but it always returns an empty `SP.Result`-object. I also tried (as shown in the code sample below) `CountInstances` that doesn't need a status to be passed in.

I'm assuming the the `subscription` returned from the the `SubscriptionService` is the `parentSubscription` needed by the function. I found no other way of retrieving a `subscription`.

```
var servicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web)
var instanceService = servicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService()
var subscriptionService = servicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService()
var deploymentService = servicesManager.getWorkflowDeploymentService()
// ...
var subs = subscriptionService.enumerateSubscriptionsByList(listId)
context.load(subs)
context.executeQueryAsync(() => {
  var enumerator = subs.getEnumerator()
  while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
    var sub = enumerator.get_current()
    var instances = instanceService.countInstances(sub) // empty SP.Result
  }
)
```

I did not find any further information regarding the method or this behaviour.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to pass the subscription object. `subscriptionService` has a method `getSubscription`, that you can use to get the subscription object directly.

You can find more details in my post [here](http://www.bluepowersolutions.com/2017/04/14/How-to-get-the-number-of-suspended-workflow-instances-in-a-SharePoint-list.html)

Comment: What I was missing was the loading of the context without any parameters, after calling the `countInstances` function. Your post helped me out there, thanks!